# Passing string parameter to a function or method from xhtml

Tags: jsf, el

I have a button that I'd like to render based on whether a function returns true or false.

**The HTML:**

```
<p:commandButton type="button" rendered="#{myBean.checkPermission(1)}" value="Create"  />
```

**And the supporting bean:**

```
public boolean checkPermission(String actionKey) {
...
}
```

The problem is that when I call checkPermission with a numeric parameter like

`#{myBean.checkPermission(1)}`,

it works fine, but with I pass a String as a parameter, i.e.

`#{myBean.checkPermission(ABC)}`

, I get an empty string passed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not passing a `String`, instead an `ABC` variable that can't be understood by EL and your method will receive `null` value (thanks to BalusC for correct me). You should add apostrophes (') to tell the framework you're passing a `String`:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" rendered="#{myBean.checkPermission('ABC')}"
    value="Create" />
```

Comment: It's more specifically EL which didn't understood it. The variable `#{ABC}` didn't exist in the EL scope and evaluates to `null`. This is beyond JSF's control.